# How to check the current url in php, then compare it to see if it has an sepecific word/phrase

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Basically i created an function that redirects  a user if they try to access http://example.com/wp-longin.php directly.

The function below works.
The problem is that i have changed the url for wp-login.php from http://example.com/wp-login.php to http://example.com/here

```
function access_granted(){
     global $pagenow;
     if(!isset($_GET['action']) && 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
      wp_redirect('http://example.com/');
      exit();
     }
    }
```

My question is, is there a way to check the url  only when it contains "here" and make sure it contains "action" or else be redirected back home using php?

the reason that makes this difficult, is that i have this in the functions.php file as i do not want to edit core wp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine the current URI.

Note: Don't rely on entries in `$_SERVER` being there if your script should be runnable from the command line.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php